# Unable to install pip in ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to install pip several times but couldn't. This is how my terminal looks like while trying to install pip:

```
aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ pip

The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip

aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo pip

sudo: pip: command not found

aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$
```

Comment: Sounds like your `$PATH` is set to something your distro is not expecting.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes I thought about it too... but why uninstalling and purging the package and installing again worked then? maybe some conflict with the dependencies?

Comment: you can use python-pip like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724749/8253704

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try with this commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-pip

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install python-pip

curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"

python get-pip.py
```

verify:

```
pip --help

pip -V
```

The issue might be package available in Ubuntu 14.04 Universe repository.

If that doesn't work, download the .deb from here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python-pip/download

and right click on the .deb and install it

Comment: I have tried 10 times but couldn't able to resolve this.
I have also tried install python3-pip but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AmanKumar okey then, check my updated answer, I think I know what is it

Comment: **After trying `python get-pip.py` command I gets this :**

`You are using pip version 1.5.4, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

_aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$_ pip --help

The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip

_aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$_  pip install --upgrade pip

The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip

_aman@aman-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$_ `

Comment: @AmanKumar I updated again. Try download the .deb and install it manually, it is indeed really rare...

Comment: I tried that but it says **A later version is already installed**.
I didn't able to uninstall pip because `pip uninstall pip` command is not working here.

Comment: do sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-pip @AmanKumar, and then follow the commands above

Comment: @AmanKumar Fantaaaaaaaaaastic! don't forget to accept the answer with (✓)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @TaylorLiss I have always loved to help

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is probably you have two versions of python 2 installed on your PC in different locations and pip of one of the copies of python got removed somehow. so when you try to install the pip for a copy, system says that there is a pip already installed in another location and also the /usr/local/bin folder is also missing the pip file used to installed pip.

i just solved this issue so i will try to explain it in a way so that beginners also understand it properly

copy the already installed pip file to the location where it is missing instead of installing it through commands as command will detect the already installed pip.

the solution is very simple:

run these commands in a terminal (command prompt) in Ubuntu

> which pip

# to get the location of the pip file already installed

> cp location provided by which pip location where to copy pip file

hope it helps.