# "E: Unable to locate package python-pip" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install virtualenv on Ubuntu.

First it said `command 'pip' not found`, so I typed

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

then it said

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I tried to reset WSL, download using cmd but it doesn't work with Ubuntu. I don't know why. Even though I have downloaded python3, virtualenv, and pip using cmd. It doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04. It also fails on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
aiki@LAPTOP-886AEJJG:~$ pip

Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip

aiki@LAPTOP-886AEJJG:~$ sudo apt install python-pip
[sudo] password for aiki:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I'm trying to install jarvis and mycroft on win 10, but I need to use Ubuntu because it only works with Linux.

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install pip in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44296498/608639)

Comment: you can use python-pip , https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724749/8253704

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try following command sequence on Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: what does this mean                                                                                                                            "aiki@LAPTOP-886AEJJG:~/Jarvis$ ./setup.sh
Specify python version(2/3)(Default-3)3
Selected python version 3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'"

Comment: make sure python3 and pip3 if you are using version 3 and also make sure about the module that you have imported is i stalled using pip3. check the python version and pip version then check if the imported module on your code is available under those versions of python and pip.

Comment: for any other new problem, post new question on stack overflow but first search stack overflow for you new problem.

Comment: how do i check the pip version? do i just type pip3?

Comment: `pip --version` and `python --version`. For you new problem, post new question on stack.

Comment: @Aiki use `python3 -m pip --version`

Comment: Does not work in a docker container derived from ubuntu:latest

Comment: Does not work in a google instance

Answer (score 108):

```
ls /bin/python*
```

Identify the highest version of python listed.
If the highest version is something like `python2.7` then install `python2-pip`
If its something like `python3.8` then install `python3-pip`

Example for python3.8:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: Hi, 

I have python2.7 installed in "/usr/lib/python2.7" and "/usr/local/bin/python2.7", when I run "sudo apt-get install python2-pip" it gives same error: "Unable to locate package python2-pip"

ls /bin/python* outputs: 
bin/python3  /bin/python3.8  /bin/python3-futurize  /bin/python3-pasteurize

Is my python2.7 installed on wrong place?

Comment: This is the right answer for most having this problem IMHO.

Comment: I agree with @desgua.In my case whenever I ran `python --version` from the terminal it said `Python 2.7.2`. When I checked in the `/bin/python*`, however, there were several other 3.x versions installed. Worth checking out.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python2-pip` yields `E: Unable to locate package python2-pip`

Answer (score 43):

Try the following commands in terminal, this will work better:

```sh
apt-get install curl

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 10):

On some kind of Linux, like distros based on Debian, you might want to consider updating your '**apt-get**' first, in case you are installing python-pip through it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This might help apt-get to update its indexes and locate the python-pip package.
After this, u might install it like this-

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip (Python2)
sudo apt-get install python3-pip (Python3)
```

Answer (score 5):

You might have python 3 pip installed already. Instead of `pip install` you can use `pip3 install`.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem of:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

you should do this. This works with the python2.7 and you not going to get disappointed by it.
follow the steps that are mention below.
go to [**get-pip.py**](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py) and copy all the code from it.
open the terminal using CTRL + ALT +T

```
vi get-pip.py
```

paste the copied code here and then exit from the vi editor by pressing

```
ESC then :wq => press Enter
```

lastly, now run the code and see the magic

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

It automatically adds the pip command in your Linux.
[you can see the output of my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5LfW.png)

Answer (score -1):

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 10 and I had the same issue. Try the way which helped me to fix this. I assume that you are using python3.

```
python3 get-pip.py
sudo apt install python3-pip
```