# How to install Pip on a new Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I posted the question below, but none of the answers I was pointed to  worked, though they look like they should.

I activated (again) the virtualenv.  It still tells me that pip can't be found by apt when doing an 'apt install' command.  But here is where I am now, and very confused.

I pointed my directory to "/home/.../q7root/bin/pip" and did an "ls".  It shows a sub-directory with pip in it (or, I think, a link to it - I'm not the best at Unix).  When I type "which pip" I get the path to this point ('q7root/pip').  bit if I just type "pip" at the CLI I get I get this error:

[image: pip error]

I have looked at my PATH, and this q7root/bin is the first place to look on the path.  And, despite trying mightily with all the references people gave me, pip3 never gets installed.

But even pip is challenged.  "which pip" points to this copy in the virtual environment site, but typing "pip" as a command tells me 'No module named pip.'

So pip seems to need more stuff installed (?), or there is some mess.  Any advice?

**Original Question:**

*At the suggestion of others working on what was a functional Django project, I upgraded to a more recent version of Ubuntu (18).
However, when I first try to run it it blows up at line 3 of the initial script module when asked to import django as a package.
I tried `pip -r requirements.txt`, but the system said pip was an unknown package.  I dropped down and used apt to load pip onto my machine (`sudo apt-get pip`), then tried using pip itself (`pip update pip`) which failed.:

[image: Pip load error message]

I also tried `pip install django`, and got this:

[image: django not found]

I would have thought an OS upgrade would not require re-installing all currently installed packages (seems like a no-brainer to do the work of installing everything that had been installed).  But right now I am terribly stuck...obviously, having 'pip' let's you (at least) have a basic CLI tool.
Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["E: Unable to locate package python-pip" on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422929/e-unable-to-locate-package-python-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of python.

**Python 3**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

**Python 2**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

[How to Install Pip on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/#:%7E:text=To%20install%20Python%202%20and%20pip%20for%20Python,will%20look%20something%20like%20this%3A%20pip%20...%20)

Comment: I tried all of these to no positive effect.  It looks a bit more confused and virtual environments are part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a fresh Ubuntu install. I think you've run too many commands for your current setup to be reproduceable.

Install `python3` and `python3-venv`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-venv
```

Use the `venv` module to create the virtual env.

```
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

You now have access to `pip` in the venv.

It's OK to upgrade pip in the virtual env, I suggest you don't ever upgrade the system `pip` otherwise you might hit issues [like this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221).

```
(myenv) python -m pip --version
(myenv) python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now you can use `pip` to install your requirements in the virtual env.

```
(myenv) python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In the above commands I've used `python -m pip` instead of `pip`. This is the recommended way, as it ensures that you are using the version of `pip` that matches `python`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this was a state of deep computer confusion.  I was already disk-limited so I bought a new computer, and this error did not recur with the same code being used.