# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, sudo, apt-get

I have the following `Dockerfile` where I want to build a Docker container from the image at https://hub.docker.com/r/julianassmann/opencv-cuda/:

```
FROM julianassmann/opencv-cuda 
#image name with OpenCV with CUDA

# Edit /etc/default/docker file to add custom DNS server
RUN echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.16.16.10"' >> /etc/default/docker

#working directory where i have placed container 
#on top of container
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install sudo

# Install additional packages
RUN sudo apt update \
    #prevent interactive prompts
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt install -y lubuntu-desktop net-tools pip python3-tk \
    # Clean up no longer required by any other packages 
    && apt autoremove -y \
    #removes cached package files that were downloaded during the package installation
    && apt clean -y \
    #cached package lists and can be safely removed after installing packages
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    #removes any files with names starting with reboot-required in the /run/ directory to prevent reboot after installing packages
    && rm /run/reboot-required*

# Create a non-root user with sudo priviledges
ARG USERNAME=user
ARG PASSWORD=password
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID # Group ID (GID) of the user being created
#Creates a group with the specified USER_GID and name USERNAME
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    #Creates a user with the specified USER_UID, USER_GID, USERNAME, and encrypted password generated from the PASSWORD. 
    #The -m flag ensures that a home directory is created for the user.
    #/bin/bash refers to the Bash shell executable binary file. Unix-like operating system,you specify the user's default shell
    && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME -p $(openssl passwd $PASSWORD) \
    # [Optional] Add sudo support for the non-root user
    && apt update \
    && apt install -y sudo \
    #username allow execute commands as root without entering a password
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
    #Sets appropriate permissions
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    # Clean up
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && apt clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # provide auto-completion functionality when typing commands in the Bash shell
    && echo "source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc \
    # Configure remote desktop
    RUN adduser xrdp ssl-cert
RUN sed -i '3 a echo " \
    export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=Lubuntu\\n\
    export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11\\n\
    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt\\n\
    export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/etc/xdg\\n\
    " > ~/.xsessionrc' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
#default port used by Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)
EXPOSE 3389

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir -U -r requirements.txt \
    && rm requirements.txt

# Start xrdp and a bash terminal
CMD service xrdp start ; bash
```

I have the following error:

> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

I don't understand the problem as I have installed `sudo` with the previous commands:

```
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install sudo
```

Comment: Why do you think the error has anything with `sudo` to do?

Comment: You can't just jump to the final error message telling you that apt failed -- you need to look at the logs that describe _how_ it failed (and include those logs in the question!).

Comment: You rarely if ever need `sudo` in a Docker context.  In your Dockerfile, you're already the root user.  For the main container process, you can select what user it runs as using the `docker run -u` option.  It's also very difficult to set up securely (is your password really `password`; do you care that it's in plain text in `docker history`; what are you gaining if the user can run literally any command as root so long as they say `sudo` first).  If you believe the `sudo` setup is part of the problem, a starting point might be to remove it entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your `Dockerfile` and first error which you also stated is connected with `apt-get update`, it states that it can not find signatures (Public part of GPG keys) for `nvidia` packages.

> 5.095 W: GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC
>
> 5.095 E: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease' is not signed.

I found the solution for this part on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444943/nvidia-gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-publi

Fix is to add public keys before your apt-get update

```
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install sudo
```

Like so.

When this step was done I tried rebuilding the image again, and then you have an error with installing `pip` on Ubuntu 18.

On this line:

```
     && apt install -y lubuntu-desktop net-tools python3-pip python3-tk \
```

> 2.876 Reading state information...
>
> 2.937 E: Unable to locate package pip

And the fix for this is found here:

["E: Unable to locate package python-pip" on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422929/e-unable-to-locate-package-python-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Which says you need to install `python3-pip` instead of just `pip` for the `python3` dependency.

Which makes it:

```
&& apt install -y lubuntu-desktop net-tools python3-pip python3-tk \
```

The whole `Dockerfile` with these adjustments is:

```
FROM julianassmann/opencv-cuda 
#image name with OpenCV with CUDA

# Edit /etc/default/docker file to add custom DNS server
RUN echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.16.16.10"' >> /etc/default/docker

#working directory where i have placed container 
#on top of container

RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install sudo

# Install additional packages
RUN apt update \
    #prevent interactive prompts
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt install -y lubuntu-desktop net-tools python3-pip python3-tk \
    # Clean up no longer required by any other packages 
    && apt autoremove -y \
    #removes cached package files that were downloaded during the package installation
    && apt clean -y \
    #cached package lists and can be safely removed after installing packages
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    #removes any files with names starting with reboot-required in the /run/ directory to prevent reboot after installing packages
    && rm /run/reboot-required*

# Create a non-root user with sudo priviledges
ARG USERNAME=user
ARG PASSWORD=password
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID # Group ID (GID) of the user being created
#Creates a group with the specified USER_GID and name USERNAME
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    #Creates a user with the specified USER_UID, USER_GID, USERNAME, and encrypted password generated from the PASSWORD. 
    #The -m flag ensures that a home directory is created for the user.
    #/bin/bash refers to the Bash shell executable binary file. Unix-like operating system,you specify the user's default shell
    && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME -p $(openssl passwd $PASSWORD) \
    # [Optional] Add sudo support for the non-root user
    && apt update \
    && apt install -y sudo \
    #username allow execute commands as root without entering a password
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
    #Sets appropriate permissions
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    # Clean up
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && apt clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # provide auto-completion functionality when typing commands in the Bash shell
    && echo "source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc \
    # Configure remote desktop
    RUN adduser xrdp ssl-cert
RUN sed -i '3 a echo " \
    export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=Lubuntu\\n\
    export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11\\n\
    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt\\n\
    export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/etc/xdg\\n\
    " > ~/.xsessionrc' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
#default port used by Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)
EXPOSE 3389

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir -U -r requirements.txt \
    && rm requirements.txt

# Start xrdp and a bash terminal
CMD service xrdp start ; bash
```

NOTE:

You still have one more error to solve:

> [ 9/11] RUN sed -i '3 a echo "     export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=Lubuntu\n    export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11\n    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt\n    export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/etc/xdg\n    " > ~/.xsessionrc' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh:
> 0.419 sed: can't read /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh: No such file or directory

But I commented out this line from the `Dockerfile`, and it was built, Using the command `docker image build -t cuda-test:0.0.1 .`

Comment: Note that in general, it's not obligatory or expected for folks to do their own investigation of the type you have here (trying to determine the unstated-by-the-OP immediate cause); we want the OP to edit the logs of the failure they experienced _into the question_, because otherwise we're relying on an _assumption_ that you reproduced the same problem (as opposed to a new/different one their code was also subject to) without proof. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the first bullet point within.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much that really helped me a lot!! In the end I have used another base image as the one I was using required very outdated versions of packages.