# Unable to locate package python-pip Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install mininet-wifi. After downloading it, I have been using the following command to install it:

```
    sudo util/install.sh -Wlnfv
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
    E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I have tried multiple times to download python-pip. I know mininet-wifi utilizes python 2 instead of python 3. I have tried to download python-pip using the command:

```
    sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

But that leads to the same error:

```
    E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to report this as a bug against mininet-wifi. Python 2 was end-of-lifed at the beginning of this year. It won't be receiving any further bug or security fixes. Projects should be using Python 3 now.

Comment: Try repository universe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423104/7976758

Comment: Mininet-WiFi supports Python3. This seems to be a problem with internal packages than any other thing. Worth mentioning that Ubuntu 20.04 does not (natively) support Python2 anymore. So you may want to install pip3. Unless there is a good reason to use Python2...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

***Pip for Python 2 is not included in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories.  
 You need to install pip for Python 2 using the get-pip.py script.***

---

*1. Start by enabling the universe repository:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

*2. Update the packages index and install Python 2:*

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python2
```

*3. Use curl to download the get-pip.py script specific to python 2.7:*

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
```

*4. Once the repository is enabled, run the script as sudo user with python2 to install pip :*

```
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

---

---

Pip will be installed globally. If you want to install it only for your user, run the command without sudo. The script will also install setuptools and wheel, which allow you to install source distributions

*Verify the installation by printing the pip version number:*

```
pip2 --version
```

The output will look something like this:

```
 pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: That was a great solution. Thanks. I've encountered the error you mentioned as "If an error occurs".  I think the problem is with using python2.7 with Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Its not working! ```root@farm:~# python --version
Python 2.7.18
root@farm:~# python ./get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get-pip.py", line 24244, in <module>
    main()
  File "./get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "./get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpc8gemv/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: @a0s use `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py` as it has been said in the answer if you get an error.

Comment: Done all the above commands. In my case pip3 has been installed but the error still exists

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 2 is past its end-of-life, few packages for Python2 are included in 20.04. You have to install `pip` for Python 2 manually:

First, install Python 2:

```
sudo apt install python2
```

Then, follow https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ , using `python2`:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python2 get-pip.py
```

You can run the second step with `sudo`. If you don't use `sudo`, you'll need to change `PATH`, as suggested by the installation message. Alternatively, and possibly better (since it doesn't change `PATH`), use

```
python2 -m pip
```

whenever you need pip2.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the curl command for downloading `get-pip.py` gave a syntax error on running `sudo python get-pip.py`.

But manual download by visiting https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ and downloading `get-pip.py` worked fine for me.

Comment: thanks, had the same issue. I think aftrer jan 2021 people are having this problem

Answer (score 2):

I've found that creating a `virtualenv` for Python 2.7 installs also `pip`

```
$ virtualenv -p python2 venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/.../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: It seems to me that it only install it inside the virtual environment, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Put `python3` instead `${PYPKG}` in line 202, and instead `python-pip` in line 596 in file `install.sh` of mininet-wifi.

Answer (score -2):

To solve the problem of:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

Run the package update index cmd:

```
sudo apt update
```

If not that, then `python-pip-whl` (which is also a package installer) is available in the `universe` repository, make sure that's installed and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip-whl
```

Comment: The [list of Python-related packages for 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python/) shows no `python-pip` package.

Comment: Can `python-pip-whl` not install python packages from the [python package index](https://pypi.org) ?

Answer (score -2):

I specifically needed a Dockerfile file and this is what I have put inside so that it works without errors, I hope it will help someone.

This is Dockerfile file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev
WORKDIR /app
COPY .  /app
ENV DEBUG=True
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood: are you sure this answers the question?